# Proof with $\delta z = z-z_0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove the following:

Write $\delta z = z-z_0$ and show that $$\lim_{z \rightarrow z_0} f(z) = w_0 \iff \lim_{\delta z \rightarrow 0} f(z_0 + \delta z) = w_0$$

I get that it's like proving the derivative but the if and only if part confuses me. I'm also trying to find a way to write some kind of denominator but I got lost as well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: $z_{0} + \delta z = z$, $\delta z\to 0\Longleftrightarrow z- z_{0}\to 0\Longleftrightarrow z\to z_{0}$.

Comment: It sounds like you're focusing too much on a vague similarity with the derivative - this statement has virtually nothing to do with derivatives, and looking for a denominator is a red herring! As a starting point, try writing out the *definition* of the limit in each case, and see if you can spot a similarity you can make use of.